# OctoberCMS | Builder | Repeat Project Module Error

Tags: plugins, repeater, octobercms

I've built repeater feature using the plugin builder for OctoberCMS and started using it in project post. The error said that "Data too long for column 'project_module'", project_module is repeater field name and am not sure what to do next to solve the error.

Have anyone encounter similar error after putting together the repeater feature and tried to populate the repeater function in post etc?

Any help would be great

Here is the printed error if anyone is interested.

```
"SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'project_module' at row 1 (SQL: update `wt_project_` set `project_module` = [{"project_module_title":"Business Card","card_orientation":"double","project_asset":"project_image","video_url":"","project_images":"\/IMG_0040.jpg","viewing_style":"single_image","project_text":""},{"project_module_title":"","card_orientation":"single","project_asset":"project_image","video_url":"","project_images":"\/IMG_0128.jpg","viewing_style":"carousel","project_text":""}], `wt_project_`.`updated_at` = 2022-03-21 05:33:38 where `id` = 1)" on line 669 of C:\laragon\www\axisdynamics\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php
```

Answer (score 2):

Database field `project_module` should be of MySQL type `text` (also jsonable in model).